# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^{-2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^{-2}}dx$$ with precision of $\frac{1}{1000}$

So we first take the $e^x$ sequence and plugin in $x^{-2}$ so we get

$$\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}dx=\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{(x^2)^n}{n!}dx$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Not following your calculation...trusting that $t$ is a constant (and not a function of $x$), just use the fact that $\int_0^1x^c\,dx=\frac 1{1+c}$ (trusting that $c\neq -1$.  For $c=-1$ the integral fails to converge).

Comment: Did you possibly mean $\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx$?   I mean...your series expansions don't even involve $t$.

Comment: @lulu yes deeply sorry, fixed the question

Comment: if you use WolframAlpha you will get $$\frac{1}{e}-\sqrt{\pi } \text{erfc}(1)$$

Comment: Ok, well in that case just integrate your power series term by term.  As the result alternates (and the terms decrease to $0$ in absolute value) the error is bounded by the first omitted term.

Comment: @lulu which part of the power series I need to integrate? $\frac{1}{n!}$? as $x$ is a constant?

Comment: $x$ is certainly not a constant!  it varies from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Your series starts out as $1-\frac {x^2}{1!}+\frac {x^4}{2!}+\cdots$.  So the indefinite integral looks like $x-\frac {x^3}{3\times1!}+\frac {x^5}{5\times2!}+\cdots$ and so on.

Comment: @lulu so I get$ \sum (-1)^n \frac{-x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1}$

Comment: Not sure you've got the signs right.  But close. Always write out the first couple of terms as a check. For the indefinite integral.  Now you need to evaluate at the limits of the integral.

Comment: @lulu so I take the general term of the reminder $|R_{n}|<\frac{1}{(n+1)!(2n+3)}<\frac{1}{1000}$ and get than $n\ge 3$

Comment: I think $n=3$ is too small, no?  Your fraction becomes $ \frac 1{4!\times 9}=\frac 1{216}$.

Comment: Once you have the approximation, you can check it against a table of values for the error function (or use WolframAlpha to get a high precision answer).  Just get your value first.

Comment: NOTE:  I have been assuming you meant $e^{-x^2}$ as your integrand.  if you really meant $e^{-x^{-2}}$ (as you have written) then your series is wrong.